# Converting NUnit Test Project to MS Test

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit, mstest

Has anyone tried to replace NUnit tests with MS Test, and would be willing to share any tips or points about the complexity?  I was considering this, but I have a lot of tests, so outside of assembly/type switching/attribute replacement and all, any pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out: http://www.stormbase.net/converting-from-nunit-to-mstest
Note step #5.

Comment: the referenced page no longer exists